# Get title of Wordpress page in included PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, include, title

(Long time reader, first time writer)
I have a wordpress installation where the pages each display a table of information that is different based on which page it's on. I was trying to use the page title as the variable that tells the table what to display with this code:

```
<?php $post_title = the_title(); ?>
<?php $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent); ?>
```

...to get the page title as well as the parent page's title. The table I want to display is in a php include command in the page template. However, it looks like variables from the page template won't carry over into the included php page. How can I get the page title into a variable I can use in the included php?

Comment: `the_title()` does output, so you won't capture anything. That's why wp has all the `get_the_whatever()` functions, which return data instead of outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

The function below takes 2 parameters, the included file, and an array of params. Eg:

```
render('yourfile.php', array('title' => 'Your title'));
```

**Function:**

```
<?php
function render($file, $params)
{
    extract($params); 
    ob_start(); 
    require($file); 
    return ob_get_clean(); 
}
?>
```

You will then put `$title` inside your included file.

Comment: So, you're saying both the function definition and the render call would go in the page template? I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: "The table I want to display is in a php include command in the page template." This function will include the file you want that has the variables inside it. The variables will be set because in the function you will include the values. http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php